# Update current date field

Tags: odoo-10

In odoo 10, I have a field date take the current date:

```
current_day = fields.Date('Current Day'default=lambda *a: fields.Datetime.now())
```

Yesterday the value was '04/02/2018', and today it still has the same value.It should take '04/03/2018' and tomorrow it would be '04/04/2018'.

How can I do it?

Kind regards

Comment: Use scheduled task to update it every day.

Comment: Or you can use a computed field

Comment: Thank you both for your help.

Comment: I will prefer to use computed field @ChesuCR can you tell me how can I do it , I mean, in api.depends what should I put on?

Comment: You can leave it empty to run it always `@api.depends()`

Comment: @ChesuCR can you give me an example how to use it with computed field?

Comment: Read the [Odoo Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields) before asking please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Your model.py file:

```
from datetime import datetime

def curDate(self):
    return datetime.now().date()

current_day = fields.Date('Current Day')
```

Your xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.cron" id="update_date_value">
            <field name='name'>Update Date</field>
            <field name='interval_number'>1</field>
            <field name='interval_type'>day</field>
            <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
            <field name="active">True</field>
            <field name="model">Your-model-name-here</field>
            <field name="function">curDate</field>
            <field name="args">()</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Add this xml file into your **manifest.py** file;

Comment: Thank you so much @rahul